# Linq query FromSql where passing string value

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq

Have a SQL table example column Id-Pk-int, Name-varchar(250), ...

Using EF Core

when I execute

```
 var data= (from c in _db.Table.FromSql($"select * from Emp where id=1")
                     select c).FirstOrDefault();
```

returns successfully

but when I execute using where clause name (string)

```
 var data = (from c in _db.Table.FromSql($"select * from Emp where Name=Mike")
                     select c).FirstOrDefault();
```

I get an exception, System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: 'Invalid column name 'Mike'.'

I tested if I changed the data in the database column: Name to 123 (number) it works but fails when value is string

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. I think the problem is occured because of you forgot to use `'` symbol. Because exception says there is no column named Mike. And column name should be "Name" as i see from the code.
2. Check if `Name` column is `VARCHAR`. If the column is `VARCHAR` you need use ' symbols. If not you can use like `WHERE ID=1`

Use that;

```
   var data = (from c in _db.Table.FromSql($"select * from Emp where Name='Mike'")
                     select c).FirstOrDefault();
```

Edit 2: I see that you said Id-int, Name-varchar. Can you use the code i wrote? Thanks.

Comment: You absolutely correct! Good catch! Thanks for your help!

Comment: You are welcome. I am glad that i helped :)

Comment: Use parameters, don't concat/interpolate data into a query

Comment: @Charlieface That's not concating or interpolating, it's a hard coded value.

Comment: @juharr OP is clearly using interpolation in their real code, as indicated by `$` and the fact that it doesn't make sense to hard-code a search value like that, even though in the question they have edited the value straight in

Answer (score 0):

You should use proper parameterization, **do *not* concatenate or interpolate data into a query, or you will leave yourself open to injection attacks and syntax errors.**

```cs
var data = (from c in _db.Table.FromSql("select * from Emp where Name = @name",
                   new SqlParameter("@name", SqlDbType.VarChar, 50){Value = "Mike"})
                     select c).FirstOrDefault();


var data = (from c in _db.Table.FromSql("select * from Emp where Id = @id",
                   new SqlParameter("@id", SqlDbType.Int){Value = 1})
                     select c).FirstOrDefault();
```

In newer versions of EF Core, use `FromSqlRaw` in the same way.